# python socket:send and receive multi objects data

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, python-3.x, networking

i working on a multi player game project its strategy so i need to sending data for more that one object in the same time i created a client and server  and that's worked for one object in the server and one object in the client but after i added the second object to the server i get a  error in the second object script
for example 
the server have two objects that's i can get access to control it ["Cube"] and ["Server"]
and the server have only one object that's called ["Client"]
the proplem is when i run server then i controll my objects the engine swaping the objects in the client screen
for example whe i click up arrow to move the ["Server"] object to up the ["Cube"] object who moves in the Client screen
and when i click w key to move ["Cube"] object to up the ["Server"] object who moves in the client screen

that's my client code 
the ["client"] object are connected to it in the game engine

```
#------------Setup--------------#
from pickle import dumps, loads
from mathutils import Vector
from GameLogic import * 
import GameLogic as GameLogic
import bge
from socket import *
import socket
import pickle


cont = GameLogic.getCurrentController()
owner = cont.owner
#obj = cont.owner

if not owner['OneTime']:
  ServerIP = GameLogic.IP
  Serverport = 2052
  Clientname = ''
  ClientPort = 2053
  GameLogic.sClient = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

  GameLogic.sClient.bind((Clientname,ClientPort))
  GameLogic.host = (ServerIP,Serverport)    
  GameLogic.sClient.setblocking(0)
  owner['OneTime'] = 1

PosYou = list(owner.worldPosition)

scene = getCurrentScene()
Cube = scene.objects["Cube"]
Server = scene.objects["Server"]


PosServer = [0,0,0]
PosCube = [0,0,0]
#------------RECEIVE/SEND--------------#    

Data = pickle.dumps((PosYou))

GameLogic.sClient.sendto(Data,GameLogic.host)

try:
    #thefucking proplem
    Data, SRIP = GameLogic.sClient.recvfrom(1024)



    UPData = pickle.loads(Data)
    PosServer = [UPData[0],UPData[1],UPData[2]]
    Server.worldPosition = PosServer 
    Data2, SRIP2 = GameLogic.sClient.recvfrom(1024)
    UPData2 = pickle.loads(Data2)

    PosCube = [UPData2[0],UPData2[1],UPData2[2]]
    Cube.worldPosition = PosCube 




except OSError:
    pass            
#---------------THE-END----------------#
```

that's my server code 
the ["Server"] object are connected to it in the game engine

```
#------------Setup--------------#
from GameLogic import * 
import GameLogic as GameLogic
import bge
from socket import *
import socket
import pickle

from pickle import *
cont = GameLogic.getCurrentController()
owner = cont.owner
#obj = cont.owner

if not owner['OneTime']:
  Host = "localhost"
  ServerPort = 2052
  GameLogic.sServer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
  GameLogic.sServer.bind((Host,ServerPort)) 
  GameLogic.sServer.setblocking(0)
  owner['OneTime'] = True

PosYou = list(owner.worldPosition)

scene = getCurrentScene()
Client = scene.objects["Client"]
Cube = scene.objects["Cube"]
PosClient = [0,0,0]
PosCube = [0,0,0]
#------------RECEIVE/SEND--------------#

try:
    Data, CLIP = GameLogic.sServer.recvfrom(1024)
    UPData = pickle.loads(Data)
    PosClient = [UPData[0],UPData[1],UPData[2]]
    Client.worldPosition = PosClient 
    Data = pickle.dumps((PosYou))
    GameLogic.sServer.sendto(Data,CLIP)  


except OSError:
    pass
#---------------THE-END----------------#
```

the second object code the ["Cube"] object and that's connected two the object in the game engine 
and i get this error when i run it

> File "secondob.py", line 18, in  AttributeError: 'module'
>   object has no attribute 'sServer'

```
#------------Setup--------------#
from GameLogic import * 
import GameLogic as GameLogic
import bge
from socket import *
import socket
import pickle

from pickle import *
cont2 = GameLogic.getCurrentController()
owner2 = cont2.owner
#obj = cont.owner





GameLogic.sServer.setblocking(0)
PosYou2 = list(owner2.worldPosition)


scene = getCurrentScene()
Client = scene.objects["Client"]
PosClient2 = [0,0,0]
#------------RECEIVE/SEND--------------#

try:

    Data2, CLIP2 = GameLogic.sServer.recvfrom(1024)


    UPData2 = pickle.loads(Data2)
    PosClient2 = [UPData2[0],UPData2[1],UPData2[2]]

    Client.worldPosition = PosClient2     
    Data2 = pickle.dumps((PosYou2))
    GameLogic.sServer.sendto(Data2,CLIP2)  
except OSError:
    pass
#---------------THE-END----------------#
```

Comment: Have you seen the big red warning in the python [pickle documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)? Never unpickle data you received over the network! Using pickle to implement a multiplayer game is a terrible idea. It's very easy to change any client to execute arbitrary code on the server.

Comment: so what i can replace with it ?

Comment: This question is very unclear. It seems you are saying that you get no error, that the code runs, but gives the wrong result. Then you post an error that you say the code gives you, which seems to have nothing to do with the problems you mentioned before. (And can't really be diagnosed from the code you've posted.) So it seems as if half your question is talking about one version of your code, and the other half about another version of your code. Please [edit] to clarify what your real question is.

Comment: @MohamedSharkwy - `json` would be one option, or `xml`, or if that's overkill you can go with a simple custom text or binary protocol. Just don't use pickle for something like this!

Comment: Looks like you were limiting your read to 1024 bytes and 2 objects don't fit into that.